# Thunderbird doesn't show folders on a new Dovecot install

Tags: email, dovecot, thunderbird

I set up a new mailserver with postfix and **Dovecot** some days ago, everything is working except for **Thunderbird** not showing any folders.

Evolution shows me all folders.

I migrated from a Courier install using imapsync.

In the filesystem the folders don't have a `INBOX` in their name, so the tho folders ar called `.Folder 1` not `.INBOX.Folder 1`.

This is the output of `dovecot -n`:

```
# 1.0.10: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
Warning: mail_extra_groups setting was often used insecurely so it is now deprecated, use mail_access_groups or mail_privileged_group instead
base_dir: /var/run/dovecot/
log_timestamp: “%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ”
protocols: imap pop3
listen(default): *:143
listen(imap): *:143
listen(pop3): *:110
disable_plaintext_auth: no
login_dir: /var/run/dovecot//login
login_executable(default): /usr/lib/dovecot/imap-login
login_executable(imap): /usr/lib/dovecot/imap-login
login_executable(pop3): /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3-login
first_valid_uid: 1001
last_valid_uid: 1001
mail_extra_groups: vmail
mail_access_groups: vmail
mail_location: maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%u
maildir_copy_with_hardlinks: yes
mail_executable(default): /usr/lib/dovecot/imap
mail_executable(imap): /usr/lib/dovecot/imap
mail_executable(pop3): /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3
mail_plugin_dir(default): /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/imap
mail_plugin_dir(imap): /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/imap
mail_plugin_dir(pop3): /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/pop3
pop3_uidl_format(default): 
pop3_uidl_format(imap): 
pop3_uidl_format(pop3): %08Xu%08Xv
auth default:
  user: nobody
  passdb:
    driver: sql
    args: /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
  userdb:
    driver: sql
    args: /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
  socket:
    type: listen
    client:
      path: /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
      mode: 432
      user: postfix
      group: postfix
    master:
      path: /var/run/dovecot/auth-master
      mode: 432
      user: vmail
      group: vmail
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why but Thunderbird hadn't subscribed to the folders. I did so and everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `namespace` definition.  You almost certainly do not have the autosubscribe option set, or else you added it later after Thunderbird had already probed the server.

Make sure you have the `auto=subscribe` option set on the relevant folders:

`namespace inbox {
  separator = /
  inbox = yes
  mailbox "*" {
  }
  mailbox "Drafts" {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox "Sent" {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Spam" {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Junk
    autoexpunge = 30d
  }
  mailbox "Trash" {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Trash
  }
}`

Then, completely remove the definition from Thunderbird, and recreate it.  Thunderbird will re-probe the IMAP, and will autosubscribe to the folders.